# Convert sinusoidal form to exponential form

Tags: complex-numbers, fourier-series

How do I get from

$$-2j=\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right) + 2j\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)$$

to the following?

$$-2j=2e^{-j\frac{\pi}{2}}$$

---

Background:

Given $x(t)=10+3\cos\omega_0t+5\cos(2\omega_0t+30°)+4\sin3\omega_0t$, its period is $T_0=\frac{2\pi}{\omega_0}$

Using Euler's relation,

$x(t)=10+\frac{3}{2}(e^{j\omega_0t}+e^{-j\omega_0t})+\frac{5}{2}[e^{j(2\omega_0t+30°)}+e^{-j(2\omega_0t+30°)}]+\frac{4}{2j}(e^{j3\omega_0t}-e^{-j3\omega_0t})$

I'd like to know, in detail, how the last term of the equation $\frac{4}{2j}(e^{j3\omega_0t}-e^{-j3\omega_0t})$ can be rearranged to $2e^{-j\frac{\pi}{2}}e^{j3\omega_0t}+2e^{j\frac{\pi}{2}}e^{-j3\omega_0t}$.

Comment: Re: The down-vote: Is there anything wrong with the question? Could I have phrased it better?

All I'm asking is for the steps on how to represent one term of the equation in another way. My attempt was stated at the beginning of the question but I couldn't get from $\cos(\frac{\pi}{2})+2j\sin\frac{\pi}{2}$ to $2e^{-j\frac{\pi}{2}}$.

Answer (score 0):

You need to observe that $\frac{4}{2j}=-2j=-2e^{j\pi/2}=2e^{-j\pi/2}$, then the rest follows.

The result used is that if $j=e^{j\theta}=\cos(\theta)+j\sin(\theta)$ then $\theta=\pi/2+2n\pi,\mbox{ for }n=0, \pm1,...$,that is you want $\cos(\theta)=0$ and $\sin(\theta)=1$

Comment: May I know how you got from $-2j$ to $-2e^{j\pi/2}$?

Answer (score 0):

First of all,

$$-2j\neq\cos(\frac{\pi}{2})+2j\sin(\frac{\pi}{2})$$

But one can write,

$$-2j=\cos(\frac{\pi}{2})-2j\sin(\frac{\pi}{2}) \, \ldots \, Eqn.(1)$$

Adding $\cos(\frac \pi2)$ to both sides of Eqn.(1) and arranging components yields,

$$-2j + \cos(\frac \pi2) =\cos(\frac{\pi}{2}) - j\sin(\frac{\pi}{2}) + \cos(\frac \pi2) - j\sin(\frac{\pi}{2}) \, \ldots \, Eqn.(1)$$

By using the Euler's formula it can be written as,

$$-2j + \cos(\frac \pi2) =2e^{-j\pi/2} \, \ldots \, Eqn.(1)$$

*Note:*

$\cos(\frac \pi2) = \cos(\frac {-\pi}{2})$

$\sin(\frac \pi2) = -\sin(\frac {-\pi}{2})$

$\cos(\frac \pi2) = 0 $

So,

$$-2j = 2e^{-j\pi/2} \, \ldots \, Eqn.(1)$$

But these steps are unnecessary, complex exponentials has properties of real exponentials, there are shorter ways to show this equality. Also @Conrad Turner explained it before me.

Answer (score 0):

We have that by [Euler's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_identity) with real $r\ge 0$

$$re^{j\theta}=r\left(\cos \theta + j \sin \theta\right) \implies 2e^{-j\frac\pi 2}=-2j$$

in this case, since $\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)=\cos\left(-\frac{\pi}{2}\right)=0$ and $\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)=-\sin\left(-\frac{\pi}{2}\right)=1$, we have

$$2j=\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)+2j\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)=2\left[\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)+j\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)\right]=2e^{j\frac\pi 2}$$

and also

$$-2j=\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)-2j\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)=2\left[\cos\left(-\frac{\pi}{2}\right)+j\sin\left(-\frac{\pi}{2}\right)\right]=2e^{-j\frac\pi 2}$$

More in general by the same argument for any real $a$

$$aj=|a|e^{j\operatorname{sign}(a)\frac \pi 2}$$